# Find items that are related to all other items

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
public class Relation {
  public Int32 SourceId { get; set; }
  public Int32 TargetId { get; set; }
}
```

And the following list:

```
List<Relation> relations = service.GetRelations();
```

I need to select the SourceIds which are related to ALL targets.

So, given the following example with pairs `(SourceId, TargetId)`:

```
(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)
```

In this case `TargetId` can be 1 or 2.

And the only `SourceId` that is related to all `TargetIds (1, 2)` is `SourceId 1`.

`SourceId 2` is only related to `TargetId 1` and `SourceId 3` is only related to `TargetId 2`.

How can I do this?

Comment: [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: But how can I use GroupBy to get the SourceIds which are related to all TargetIds? Using GroupBy was my first idea but now sure how ... Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You say you need a LINQ answer due to EF use but `relations` is not an `IQueryable`, it is a `List<Relation>` so EF isn't involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect all possible targets ids:

```
var input = new []
{
    new Relation(1, 1),
    new Relation(1, 2),
    new Relation(2, 1), 
    new Relation(3, 2), 
};

var allTargetId = input.Select(x => x.TargetId).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Then group by source id and in each group check that all group members presented in `allTargetId`:

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x.SourceId, x => x.TargetId)
    .Where(g => allTargetId.All(x => g.Contains(x)))
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

Note: to make this code work I've added a constructor to your `Relation` class and it looks like

```
public class Relation
{
    public Relation(int sourceId, int targetId)
    {
        SourceId = sourceId;
        TargetId = targetId;
    }

    public Int32 SourceId { get; set; }
    public Int32 TargetId { get; set; }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To get `Relation`'s you can use this query:

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x.SourceId)
    .Where(g => allTargetId.All(x => g.Select(y => y.TargetId).Contains(x)))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToArray();
```

Please note that I've tested it only with linq2objects so I'm not sure how it will be translated to SQL

Comment: Is it possible at the end to get the Relation instead of the SourceId?

Comment: @MiguelMoura there are to `Relation` that match - `(1, 1), (1, 2)`. Which of them you want to get? All?

Comment: I would like to get both, if possible, because the SourceId = 1 is related to all TargetIds.

Comment: I know that the pairs (SourceId, TargetId) are unique. Knowing this is it necessary the part .GroupBy(x => x.SourceId, x => x.TargetId)?

Comment: @MiguelMoura I've updated my answer. Code in "Edit" section should return you all relations that satisfy condition

Comment: `ToList` is almost always better than `ToArray`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what you asked for. It has a form of unit test so you can check different scenarios

```
        [Fact]
        public void FindSourcesThatTargetAll()
        {
            var list = new List<Relation>
            {
                new Relation(1, 1), new Relation(1, 2), new Relation(2, 1), new Relation(3, 2)

            };
            var allTargets = list.Select(x => x.TargetId).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).ToList();

            var dict = list.GroupBy(x => x.SourceId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                grouping => grouping.Select(y => y.TargetId).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).ToList());

            var sourcesThatTargetAll = dict.Where(x => x.Value.Count == allTargets.Count).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

            Assert.Single(sourcesThatTargetAll);
            Assert.Equal(1, sourcesThatTargetAll.First());

        }
```

Basically, I did:

1. Find all the targets.
2. For every source find all targets (distinct is important) and group it by the source in the dictionary (`dict` variable)
3. From the above dictionary select all source which matches all targets (count in the example is enough, but you can make a more complicated comparison)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this would be to group the records by `TargetId`, and then find an intersection of all the `SourceId`

```
var groups = relations.GroupBy(r => r.TargetId).ToArray();
if (groups.Length > 0) {
    var set = new HashSet<int>(groups[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < groups.Length; ++i)
        set.IntersectWith(groups[i].Select(r => r.SourceId));
}
```

At the end of this `set` will contain all the `SourceId`s that are related to all `TargetId`s

Comment: I need to use only Linq as a query for entity framework

Comment: @MiguelMoura Then you should update question and tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Relation
    {
        public Int32 SourceId { get; set; }
        public Int32 TargetId { get; set; }
    }

    public Int32?[] FindRelation(Relation[] relations)
    {
        List<Int32?> sourceIds = new List<int?>;
        var countOfTargets = relations.Select(x => x.TargetId).Distinct().Count();

        var relationsGroupedBySource = relations.GroupBy(x => x.SourceId);

        foreach (var group in relationsGroupedBySource)
        {
            var distinctGroup = group.Distinct();

            if (distinctGroup.Count() == countOfTargets)
            {
                sourceIds.Add(distinctGroup.Select(x => x.SourceId).First());
            }
        }

        return sourceIds.ToArray();
    }

  public void Test()
  {
        Relation[] relations = { 
                                   new Relation() { SourceId = 1, TargetId = 1 },
                                   new Relation() { SourceId = 1, TargetId = 2 },
                                   new Relation() { SourceId = 2, TargetId = 1 },
                                   new Relation() { SourceId = 3, TargetId = 2 }
                               };

     var sourceIds = FindRelation(relations);
  }
```

Comment: I need to use only Linq and not loops as I am using Entity Framework

Comment: An explanation of your code would help the OP and others to understand your answer better. Just posting your code is confusing for others.